# Laravel: Is it possible to do a union query with Fluent or Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, fluent, eloquent

I have a complex union query that I would like to translate from MS SQL to MySQL using either Laravel's Fluent query builder or Eloquent (just guessing only Fluent could handle it).  The other alternative would be to simply us a DB Raw query, but that doesn't seem very Laravelish.

I do this as part of a recurring events engine to connect a past events history table with the futures table that holds the recurrence pattern. Here's the query if you're interested.

```
qry = "SELECT clients.p_client_id,contacts.last_name, contacts.first_name, "
qry = qry & "resource_information.last_name as res_last_name, resource_information.first_name as res_first_name, "
qry = qry & "assets.d_name, "
qry = qry & "services.service_name, " 
qry = qry & "service_recurring.id, service_recurring.client_id, service_recurring.partner_id, "
qry = qry & "service_recurring.asset_id, service_recurring.resource_id, service_recurring.service_id, "
qry = qry & "service_recurring.begin_on, service_recurring.window_beg, "
qry = qry & "service_recurring.window_end, service_recurring.rate, "
qry = qry & "service_recurring.discount, service_recurring.res_cost, service_recurring.recurring, service_recurring.id as schedule_id  "
qry = qry & "FROM service_recurring "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN clients ON service_recurring.client_id = clients.id "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN contacts ON service_recurring.client_id = contacts.client_id "
qry = qry & "AND contacts.primary_contact = 1 "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN assets ON service_recurring.asset_id = assets.id "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN resource_information ON service_recurring.resource_id = resource_information.id "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN services ON service_recurring.service_id = services.id "
qry = qry & "WHERE service_recurring.partner_id = '" & partner_id & "' "
qry = qry & "AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM service_recurring_exception WHERE rid = service_recurring.id AND exception_date = '" & thisDate & "' AND pid = '" & partner_id & "') "
qry = qry & "AND service_recurring.begin_on <= '" & thisDate & "' "
qry = qry & "AND (service_recurring.end_on >= '" & thisDate & "' OR service_recurring.end_on is null) "
qry = qry & todayis
qry = qry & "UNION "
qry = qry & "SELECT clients.p_client_id,contacts.last_name, contacts.first_name, "
qry = qry & "resource_information.last_name as res_last_name, resource_information.first_name as res_first_name, "
qry = qry & "assets.d_name, "
qry = qry & "services.service_name, "
qry = qry & "service_history.id, service_history.client_id, service_history.partner_id, "
qry = qry & "service_history.asset_id, service_history.resource_id, service_history.service_id, "
qry = qry & "service_history.begin_on, service_history.window_beg, "
qry = qry & "service_history.window_end, service_history.rate, "
qry = qry & "service_history.discount, service_history.res_cost, service_history.recurring, service_history.id as schedule_id  "
qry = qry & "FROM service_history "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN clients ON service_history.client_id = clients.id "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN contacts ON service_history.client_id = contacts.client_id "
qry = qry & "AND contacts.primary_contact = 1 "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN assets ON service_history.asset_id = assets.id "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN resource_information ON service_history.resource_id = resource_information.id "
qry = qry & "INNER JOIN services ON service_history.service_id = services.id "
qry = qry & "WHERE service_history.begin_on = '" & thisDate & "' AND service_history.partner_id = '" & partner_id & "' "
qry = qry & "AND service_history.delete_r <> 1 "
qry = qry & "ORDER BY res_last_name, d_name"
```

Comment: There are no union functions in Fluent or Eloquent in either version of L3/L4.  You can build the query up yourself and manually run it through `DB::query()` though, and I remember someone experimented with using fluent to build the inner queries and then wrapping it in a raw union query.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Phil. I'm using Laravel 4 so after converting my query to PHP I went with DB::select() and it works great!  Next I'll try and see if I can used a mixture of Fluent and a Union wrapper. I'll post back if I get it to work.